# Adding box2d header causes a torrent of compiler errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, box2d

I am experiencing either an extremely weird error or a temporary loss of brain function.

I have a box2d / cocos project running in XCode.  This all works fine but my code is currently a proof of concept "hack".  Stage one of cleaning up the code is creating classes for various objects.

Now, if I create a brand new Objective C class (inherited off NSObject) as below it all compiles fine.  As soon as I attempt to import the "Box2D.h" I receive a gazillion errors originating from the box2d library saying it cannot be built. 201 to be precise and it indicates no issues with the class itself.  Can anyone shed any light? I have already tried a clean and rebuild as well as restarting XCode.

My super complicated class definition

```
#import "Box2D.h"

@interface test : NSObject

@end
```

An example compiler error thrown

```
Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'b2Fixture' in /Users/..../libs/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `Objective-C++` file for this, because Box2D is written in C++ and thus doesn't compile in `Objective-C` out of the box. Luckily, its just a matter of renaming your file from `myClass.m` to `myClass.mm`

Answer (score 1):

A quick google turned up [the header in question](http://projects.developer.nokia.com/mototrialracer/browser/tags/1.0.0/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.h).  It looks like C++ code.  That means you'll need to compile as Objective-C++ if you want things to work.  Probably you're not doing that now - the easy way is to change your file's extention to `.mm`.